# Do i need a database for my blog website?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to web design using Wordpress. So my question might seem a little funny.

I am trying to create a blog website for a friend. It will contain few pages and pictures. There will be no data input and output required. Only comments and contact forms. Would i need a database to store the pictures, and would a database be required if we were to update new blogs every week.

Comment: essentially yes

Comment: You have set the tag "wordpress". If you're going to use that, you need everything it needs, so check out its requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has a database integrated by default, it uses MySQL as a database management system, to handle posts, pictures, comments, etc..
In other words on Wordpress you don't have to deal with the database part for normal basic usage as you describe, it is all doing it for you.
Plenty of info about this topic, for example: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-wordpress-database-management-with-phpmyadmin/ if you want to go a bit further.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

All versions of WordPress require MySql see: [Server requirements](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template:Server_requirements)

Although WordPress doesn't store pictures in the database it does store your blogs posts and comments in the database among other things.

There are probably ways around this but as a new user to WordPress I would not recommend doing anything other then setting up a standard install.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress need database to save your page, post and images links that you upload in your new blog's media. It also needs database to save the comments of the user and also the form submissions if you use some plugins like (CF7DB).

It is necessary to track the post and their comments because without database it will not be able to find the comments for specific posts or pages.

You can check the requirement need for the latest version of the wordpress on the given link below. [Requirements for wordpress](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/)